# I have a problem: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, django, heroku, server, kivy

I just loading my django project to Heroku, but i have this problem, what can i make?

remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2 (from versions: none)

remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2

Comment: do you use `kivy` in you web page? I'm not sure if it can work. `Kivy` is rather for GUI which runs directly on client's computer and it needs Graphics Environment like `Window`, `Mac`, but servers run system without Graphics Environment

Comment: searching in Google `kivy-deps.angle` I found [error when installing kivy-deps.angle , kivy-deps.glew and kivy-deps.gstreamer · Issue #8845 · pypa/pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8845) and it sees this is only for `Windows` but servers usually run `Linux`